# how can i pass login data from flask to angular2 safely

Tags: security, flask, angular2-template

in my Flask return Email info to index.html

```
return render_template("index.html", Email=Email)
```

and in my anulgar2

```
template:`{{Email}}`
export class logInTest {

public Email = window['Email'];
}
```

when i do like this I face security problems

Anyone with access to my site can fix the email

Is there no way to make it more secure?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how strict it has to be...

Base64 (as a simplest solution)

- For Python/Flask:

  ```
  from io import BytesIO
  import base64
  BytesIO(base64.b64decode|b64encode(data))
  ```
- On front-end ([JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding)):

  ```
  atob()
  btoa()
  ```

Or use two-way encryption:

- [Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto)/Flask:

  ```
  from Crypto.Cipher import AES
  obj = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, salt)
  obj2.decrypt(value)
  ```
- On front-end ([JavaScript](http://cryptojs.altervista.org/secretkey/doc/doc_aes_cryptojs-v3.html))

  ```
  CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(value, false, {format: window.CryptoJSAesJson}).toString();
  ```

Comment: i have error in BytesIO(base64.b64decode|b64encode(data))
it means encoded_text = BytesIO(base64.encodestring(Email))??

Comment: and 
return render_template("index.html", Email=encoded_text)